# Vectorising a step by step simulation in R

Tags: r

I've written a script in R where I'm simulating the flow of stock in and out of a warehouse:

```
set.seed(10)

#Create dataframe
df1 <- data.frame(date = seq(1,20),
                  #Stock in to warehouse on date
                  stockIn = round(10+10*runif(10),0),
                  #Stock out of warehouse on date
                  stockOut = round(10+10*runif(10),0))

#The initial inventory level of the warehouse on date 1
initBalance <- 20

#Create a column of NAs which holds the end of day stock level
df1$endStockBalance <- NA

#Loop through each day
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  #If it's the first day, put initBalance into endStockBalance 
  if(i == 1){
    df1[i,4] <- initBalance
  #For other days, take the maximum of the previous day's inventory plus the difference between stock in and stock out, and 0 (we can't have negative stock levels)
  } else {
    df1[i,4] <- max(df1[i-1,4] + df1[i,2] - df1[i,3],0)
  }
}
```

This works with a for loop, but I want to know if there's a more elegant approach through vectorising it, as this is fine for small lists, but it'll be pretty slow for a larger number.

I've looked at using `lag` in `dplyr` but because of the step by step nature of the script that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can basically change the loop to

```
cumsum(c(initBalance, df1$stockIn[-1] - df1$stockOut[-1]))
#[1] 20 17 20 21 18 16 18 18 20 16 14 11 14 15 12 10 12 12 14 10
```

which is same as your `endStockBalance` which we get after running `for` loop

```
identical(df1$endStockBalance, 
           cumsum(c(initBalance, df1$stockIn[-1] - df1$stockOut[-1])))
#[1] TRUE
```

If you want to assign 0 for values which goes negative you can use `pmax`

```
pmax(cumsum(c(initBalance, df1$stockIn[-1] - df1$stockOut[-1])), 0)
```